# how to append/concat unrelated dataframes in python

Tags: python, join, merge

I would like to kind append/concatenate two unrelated data frames in the way I show as follows:

Input
Table 1

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Table 2

| col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

Expected result

| col1 | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |

Does exist any function to do that? or it's only possible only with for loops?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pandas dataframe.concat see the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html